# Topologies on topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.  Is there anything like "dual space" whose points are members of $\tau$?  Would there be a natural way to define the topology on $\tau$?

Comment: Um,... you just did?

Comment: This sounds like the beginnings of the construction of Čech homology/cohomology ...

Comment: @TedShifrin do you mean Stone-Čech compactification?

Comment: @fleablood to define a topology you have to specify the open sets, not just the points.

Answer (score 1):

For one example, see the following paper and the references that Lorch cites.

Edgar Raymond Lorch, [*Continuity and Baire functions*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318011), **American Mathematical Monthly** 78 #7 (August-September 1971), 748-762.

> **(from bottom of p. 756)** In order to penetrate further into this subject it is necessary to give an appropriate structure to $T,$ the set of all coherent topologies. As mentioned earlier, this appropriate structure is itself a topology. This circumstance, that a collection of topologies is topologized, may seem a bit incestuous.

I posted this reference and quote in my 3 June 2002 sci.math post [Incestuous Mathematics](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!original/sci.math/H0FeC0NTGDU/EhuB6saiBhMJ), where you can find some other examples of a mathematical structure whose underlying set consists of elements each of which has the same (or very similar) type of mathematical structure. See also my 14 September 2006 sci.math post [The metric space of metrics](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!original/sci.math/-qQj8KG6bd8/bNqduTBbPpYJ). Incidentally, an example that I did not know about back then is [Gromov–Hausdorff convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_convergence) --- see, for example, Chapter 7 in [**A Course in Metric Geometry**](http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/akp-papers/bbi.pdf) by Burago/Iwanow/Burago (2001).

Answer (score 0):

In Stone duality, given a Boolean algebra $A$, the homomorphisms $\text{hom}(A,2)$ are the ultrafilters and make up the Stone space of $A$. Ultrafilters on $A$ is not the same thing as open sets, but they're related. And the sets that are both closed and open are in correspondence with $A$ again.

There are other versions of this duality. The $C^*$ algebra of continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space. The embedding of a space into its Stone-Čech compactification. Maximal ideals of the continuous functions on a variety with Zariski topology.

Comment: I'm looking for something where the space with underlying set $\tau$ is, of course, related to the original space, but has potential to be different in some ways.

Comment: @ForeverMozart The space _is_ different than the topology. It's the topology on the topology that's the same as the space. Analogous to the double dual of a vector space. Ultrafilters is a topology on the topology.