# Topology on a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Is there any study of putting a topology on a topology. In other words..

In topology, we start with a set $X$ and define a topology $\tau\subseteq 2^X$ satisfying certain axioms (where 2^X denotes the power set of $X$). But the set $X$ was arbitrary, so it is possible that $X$ could happen to be a topology on some other set (though, not on itself).

Conversely, say we have a set $X$ and a topology $\tau$ on $X$. Can we define a topology $\tau'$ on $\tau$?
.... well, yes! Of course we could always pick the discrete or indiscrete topology... but that doesn't seem very interesting. However there are other potential topologies using the fact that $(\tau,\subseteq )$ is a partial order. For example, for any $U\in \tau$ define $U\downarrow\in 2^{\hspace{.06cm}\tau}$ by $$
U\downarrow=2^U\cap \tau=\{V\in \tau\mid V\subseteq U\}$$
Using the fact that $(U\cap V)\downarrow=(U\downarrow)\cap(V\downarrow)$, one easily checks that the set $$\mathcal{B}(\tau)=\{\hspace{.3cm}U\downarrow\hspace{.2cm}|\hspace{.3cm} U\in \tau\hspace{.3cm}\}$$ is a basis for a topology on $\tau$. Let's call that the downward topology on $\tau$, and denote it $D(\tau)$.

Now suppose we do this process iteratively. That is, we are given some topological space $(X,\tau_1)$, and for all $n\geq 1$ define $\tau_{n+1}=D(\tau_n)$. Then we have a sequence of sets $(X=\tau_0,\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3,\ldots)$ such that $\tau_{n+1}$ is a topology on $\tau_n$ for all $n\geq 0$. Let's call such a sequence of sets an $\infty-$topological space, or just an $\infty$-topology.

Ok, so what's the point of this? Let's try an example. If we start with $\tau_0=\varnothing$ and define $\tau_{n+1}=D(\tau_n)$, then we get \begin{align*}\tau_0&=\varnothing\\\tau_1&=\{\varnothing\}=\{\tau_0\}\\\tau_2&=\{\varnothing,\tau_1\}=\{\tau_0,\tau_1\}\\\tau_3&=\{\varnothing,\{\tau_0\},\{\varnothing, \tau_1\}\}=\{\tau_0,\tau_1,\tau_2\}\\&\vdots\\\tau_{n+1}&=\{\tau_0,\tau_1,\cdots,\tau_n\}\end{align*}

So if we use the von Neumman definition of the natural numbers (i.e. axiom of infinity of set theory), then we see that $\tau_n=n=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. That's at least a little interesting! The regular old natural numbers $(0,1,2,3,4,\cdots)$ are a non-trivial example of an $\infty$-topological space! (technically, the identity function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$)

There's also the trivial examples where we define $\tau_{n+1}=2^{\tau_n}$ or $\tau_{n+1}=\{\varnothing,\tau_n\}$ to be discrete or indiscrete, respectively. But notice that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ ways to pick an $\infty$-topological space where at each step we pick $\tau_{n+1}$ to be *either* discrete *or* indiscrete. Suffice it to say, there are lots of examples...

Ok, now that we know there exist some examples, what do we *do* with them? Well, let's follow the pattern of regular topology. One of the basic definitions is what is means for a function $f:(X,\tau_X)\to (Y,\tau_Y)$ to be continuous. We say $f$ is continuous if $U\in \tau_Y\Longrightarrow f^{-1}(U)\in \tau_X$. In other words, the induced function $f^{-1}:2^Y\to 2^X$ restricts to a well-defined function $f^{-1}:\tau_Y\to \tau_X$. Now, the question is: is that function *itself* continuous? For that question to make sense we need to have topologies on $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$....

Suppose $(X_0,X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ and $(Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,\ldots)$ are $\infty$-topologies, and let $f:X_0\to Y_0$ be a function. Then it seems reasonable to define $f$ to be $\infty$-continuous if \begin{align*}f:X_0\to Y_0\\f^{-1}:Y_1\to X_1\\f^{-2}:X_2\to Y_2\\f^{-3}:Y_3\to X_3\\f^{-4}:X_4\to Y_4\\\vdots\end{align*} are all well-defined functions (Here the notation $f^{-(n+1)}$ just means the pre-image under the function $f^{-n})$.

One could also talk about induced topologies. Suppose we have some given $\infty$-topology $X=(X_0,X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ and a set $Y_0$ which we want to make into an $\infty$-topology. If we are given a function $f:X_0\to Y_0$, then we can defined $Y_1$ to be the topology co-induced by $f$, $$Y_1=\{U\subseteq Y_0\mid f^{-1}(U)\in X_1\}$$

Now we have a function $f^{-1}:Y_1\to X_1$, where $X_1$ already has the topology $X_2$. So we can define $Y_2$ to be the topology induced by $f^{-1}$: $$Y_2=\{f^{-2}(U)\mid U\in X_2\}$$

Continuing in this fashion gives an $\infty$-topology $Y=(Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,\ldots)$ such that $f:X\to Y$ is $\infty$-continuous. Likewise, we could extend many of the usual constructions/definitions from topology to $\infty$-topologies.

I guess my overall question is: Is this at all studied? I have tried to find references about it and can't find anything. Would this generalization be useful? Or would the same information be representable in terms of regular topologies somehow?

Comment: You might be interested in the notion of [hyperspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertopology) (usually understood as a topology whose points are closed sets in some other topology).

Comment: See the Mathematics Stack Exchange question [Topologies on topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2514144/13130), in particular the paper [*Continuity and Baire functions*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318011) by Lorch (1971) I cited in my answer there -- on p. 756 Lorch writes: "*This circumstance, that a collection of topologies is topologized, may seem a bit incestuous.*"